# can't capture output error from isql shell script

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, isql

I am trying to capture output and errors throw from shell script executed via isql. I've tried with the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
isql -q -i e:\test\script.sql e:\db\testdb.fdb -m -u sysuser -p xxx
```

I am looking for example how to use `–m[erge_stderr]` command.

Comment: You are not capturing output (`-o`) in the above commandline. Could you describe in more detail what you are doing, and what exactly doesn't work, and what happens instead?

Comment: I am working on window service scheduler that will trigger this upgrade script. The above script triggering using System.Process. System hang when the above process is executed. I manage to troubleshoot and found out that executing the script will return exception error. I'm trying to capture the error exception thrown so that my System.Process will not hang.

Comment: As far as I know the `-e` only works with `-o`. If you are using `System.Process`, you'll probably need to either read error yourself, or instruct it to redirect error output for you. I don't know `System.Process`, so I can't be more specific right now.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Can you provide me a workable example for -m?

Comment: Its ok Mark. I've found the solution. It works with the following code :-      isql -q -i e:\test\script.sql e:\db\testdb.fdb -o e:\error.txt -m -u sysuser -p xxx